# How to change default callback of the Microsoft authentication provider login?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, microsoft-account

In my ASP.Net Core app, I have implemented Microsoft External Login. I now wish to override the default login callback, which is listed by documentation to be `https://localhost:5001/signin-microsoft`, if of course running on localhost and on that port. The instructions on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-microsoft) then state that the callback override would be something like this: `https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback`.

I am a bit confused on where the callback is meant to be implemented. At the moment I have `ExternalLoginCallback()` callback method implemented in a base Controller class. But from looking at the above example, it doesn't look like it should be part of a controller.

Should the callback be inside `Startup.cs`, a Controller, or some other file I am not currently aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > The instructions on here then state that the callback override would be something like this: https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback.

That is related to [built-in authentication and authorization support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) in Azure App service . Do you host your app in Azure App service ?

**If yes :**

If you enable the `Authentication and authorization`feature of the app service , that means you are using the [built-in authentication and authorization support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) in Azure . That feature will take over the authentication and authorization of you application , that means authentication and authorization still works even you delete the external Azure AD authentication codes in your application . Then you could just :

1. Use `Authentication and authorization`feature of the app service , delete the Owin Microsoft Account authentication middleware related codes .
2. Disable `Authentication and authorization`feature of the app service, use [Microsoft Account external login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2)( Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount package) .

**If no :**

Then you should follow document : [Microsoft Account external login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2) . You can config the callback url by :

```
microsoftOptions.CallbackPath = "/home/about";
```

But if you are using the ASP.NET Identity template with Microsoft Account external login . After Microsoft authentication , asp.net will check whether user's identity exists in database . Since ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library. If you want to redirect user to another page after authentication , you can :

1. Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio
2. After that ,modify the redirect url in `Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Login.cshtml.cs`:

   ```
   public IActionResult OnPost(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
   {
       returnUrl = "/home/contact";
       // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
       var redirectUrl = Url.Page("./ExternalLogin", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl });
       var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
       return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
   }
   ```

Comment: You are clearly a god in the Microsoft Identity space. Cheers